# DFS Replication across WAN

Tags: windows-server-2008, replication, dfs

I have setup both sites in ADSS, set the subnets properly (I think), and setup a DFS share with replication.

How can I test that to see which physical machine I'm actually accessing when visiting \domain.local\namespace\share to ensure I'm hitting the local share and not the share over the WAN?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Right click the folder you are accessing and go to the DFS tab.  It will show you which server you are connected to.